# jQuery Validation Plugin - As soon as the form is valid

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

Question about jQuery Validate. When my form loads, I have the submit button at 50% opacity to let the user know it's disabled.

As soon as the form meets all the rules, onkeyup, how do I detect that and allow me to return the submit buttons opacity to 100%.

The "        success: function(label) {" is to late, as the requiers the user to have moved on to the next field which isn't the way it works in my app.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily hijack the validation mechanism callbacks using the [validate method options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions). Here is an example (also put it on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ibegu4/edit)):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(function() {
    var button = $('#submit1');
    function buttonHandler(validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if(errors === 0) {
            button.removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            button.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }

    $('#form1').validate({
        rules: {
            text1: { required: true }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
            buttonHandler(this);
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).addClass(errorClass);
            $(element).removeClass(validClass);
            buttonHandler(this);        
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).addClass(validClass);
            $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
            buttonHandler(this);
        }
    }).form(); // trigger validation
});
</script>
    <form id="form1" action="#">
        <input id="text1" name="text1" type="text" /><br/>
        <input id="submit1" name="submit1" type="submit" value="Test" disabled="disabled" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The key here is to trigger the validation before any user input (using the [validator.form()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/form) method), so jquery.validate starts listening to the input events, and starts triggering the callbacks when the key (and other) events fire.

Comment: thanks but it's a lot of code. I can't figure out whatt additions and what's not?

Comment: Are highlight and highlight a part of validate?

Comment: errorPlacement, highlight and unhighlight are options for the validate method, and are called when the validator shows/hides/displays error messages after the validation. The example injects a custom handler (buttonHandler), that handles the disabled attribute of the submit button according to the state of the validator.

Comment: I updated the answer, you can just copy paste the code into a blank html file and try it out yourself.

Comment: I also put it on jsbin, you can try it out online

Comment: @m0sa, ah nice I see it now. Well done. The only bug with this is by default, onload it shows the error message which is a non-ideal userexperience. How can we get the errorLabelContainer to only show up when the user clicks SUBMIT, and there is an error?

Comment: if the validation is not triggered by default (using the form() method), the messages don't show up at first, but then you need to tab or click out of a field so that the button is shown. Try it out and you'll see what i mean..

Answer (score -1):

I make this in other way. 
You have form validation on server, sure?. And why validate form data twice? In client, and on server.

My solution is send form with ajax to server, validate there, and if is no error - save data (or something...). 
If server validator find some errors, form is returned (on json...) and errors is displayed on client.

Help this?
Martin

Comment: That's a bad user experience.

Comment: When you can some difficul validate (is e-mail in db,...), only way is send data to server and validate there. Why bad experience?